# Images Not Displaying On Page or Media Gallery After Multisite Migration

Tags: images, multisite, migration

I recently migrated a WP Multisite (600+ subsites).  All of the images are in the correct folders, but just get broken images, file not found, etc.
I have tried:

- Regenerating Thumbnails via plugin and WP-CLI
- Resetting Permalinks
- File Permissions

I am at a total loss for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools to determine:

Are the URLs absolute or relative as seen in browser source?

Is the path correct for the images that throw the 404's?

If you changed domains, take a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=CLI+change+domains

Comment: URLs are absolute and correct.
Thanks for the link.  I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the WP install on the new host didn't update the .htaccess file to include the upload path

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```